# Wireless and ethernet suddenly stopped working, and laptop became slow to boot or wake from suspend

Tags: networking, 18.04

I've been using Ubuntu as my main desktop OS for a few years now. And until now I can honestly say I love it, and there had never been any problem I couldn't solve.

But this month I'm having a nightmare with it. First of all, wifi suddenly stopped working. I was working with my laptop, went to eat lunch, and when I got back it had just stopped working. After that some more problems came, for example now after I boot, or wake up the laptop from sleep, it seems to take a few minutes until it even responds(!!!).

Now, Ethernet cable connection is not working either.

I need to mention I currently run Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my Asus X556U with Intel core i7-7th gen and 16gig RAM.

Before updating from Ubuntu 16, and for a while with Ubuntu 18.04, everything was perfect.

I also want to mention that I have tried some of the solutions I found online, none of which appeared to help.

Thanks a lot for whom will save me I as am really desperate, I am using this laptop for work...

Comment: Please interrupt the boot process at the GRUB menu and boot into an earlier kernel; does the problem remain? Is networking provided by ethernet or wireless? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your quick reaponse. Now the kernel versions I see are - 4.15.0-34-generic or the same with 33-generic, and both have also recovery mode. I tried using both and nothing seems different. Any idea on how to continue?

Comment: So now one problem is solved. I tried to ping to google DNS servers (8.8.8.8), and saw that I am getting destination host unreachable, from the gateway which is used by the WIFI NIC, so I turned it off and on and now ETHERNET conncetion is working fine. but still I can't use wifi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So finally I found the answer!!!

First of all as I commented earlier, The Ethernet cable physical connection was fixed, by turning on and of the WIFI NIC, which for some reason was tried to be used as route.

Then I found this configuration file:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Where I found the line:

```
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

So I changed it to be `true`, then killed all network manager services, and started them again:

```
killall NetworkManager
service NetworkManager start
```

All Credits for the last solution goes to this old yet helpful thread:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/280417

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked for me for after applying latest updates to Ubuntu 18.04 in my Huawei MateBook 13.

Comment: This answer would be great if it could include: Why does this work? Why should it be in `managed=true`. What is its default value and if not `managed=false` what could have set it to `managed=false`. If the default is `managed=false` what is the reason for that? Is it better in most cases?

Answer (score 1):

I searched a long time for this issue after upgrading from16.04 to 18.04 and editing the /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and changing:

```
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

to

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

solved it. Every other solution I found was just workarounds and temporary fixes.